# Windows Phone 7 FTP using Sockets

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-7, ftp

I have some Windows Mobile Smart Device applications coded in Visual Studio C# that use FTP for the send/receive mechanism. It's not ideal, but it works.

I've been investigating whether these can be ported over to Windows Phone 7 and the major problem is the lack of FTP in Windows Phone. With 7.5/7.1/Mango I'm interested whether Sockets can be used but I can't find a decent wrapper out there. I've started work on my own but I was wondering if I'm just replicating work already available.

Comment: I'll leave this question open for a while in case we have any other wrappers out there. But the Eldos toolset below looks like a tidy solution.

Answer (score 2):

Our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ftps.php) component suite includes FTP/FTPS and SFTP client components for Mango.

Comment: I'll test this plug-in & let you know what I think. I personally don't mind using 3rd party DLLs if they're reliable and save me time. We're still using Sapphire FTP which we inherited from when our WinMo apps were coded in eVB.

Comment: BTW the links to the C# samples on your website are broken/missing. Should be able to figure it out from the VB.

Comment: @Craig we have extensive sample collection installed together with components (in <SecureBlackbox>\Samples folder). Samples on the site are mainly to take a quick look at components. BTW I've fixed the link on the site, thank you for pointing at the issue.

Comment: I found those samples just after I posted my last response. They work very nicely indeed! After testing the Windows Forms C# sample app, I tried a few lines in a test WP7 solution I'm looking at and after a little playing around I have everything working that I need: I can connect to an FTP server, enter username/password, list a directory, put and get. Very tidy solution! If we proceed (which might take a few weeks to decide) I'll be recommending this toolset. Nice work.