# FTP client for Windows Phone 7 Mango?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, ftp

How to utilize ftp? Is there a generic dll that I can use for an FTP client now that Mango has Sockets?

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607139/windows-phone-7-ftp-using-sockets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the [Silverlight FTP client](http://silverlightftp.codeplex.com/), you have to port the same for WP7.

Try this.