# FTP upload and download using windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to FTP download and upload via windows phone 7?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335378/ftp-client-for-windows-phone-7-mango

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FTP client for Windows Phone 7 Mango?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335378/ftp-client-for-windows-phone-7-mango)